# Search all files with same name in a directory python

Tags: python, directory, path, subdirectory, file-search

I Have a Question :
I need to get paths of a file in a directory, I have a folder that contains other folders and other folders etc.... and each of them contains a file "tv.sas7bdat" I need to get every path to that file.
Thank you !!!

Comment: Please show us, if you have tried anything on your own. It would be helpful for us.

Comment: Specifically `tv.sas7bdat` or all files that are repeated, or all files in general grouped by file name?

Comment: Does file `tv.sas7bdat` exist multiple times in the directory ?

Comment: @Alexander Ejbekov it is specific to that file because I will need to do the same process for other specific files too

Comment: @Amine Messaoudi yes it appears many times in different folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your problem right you can achieve your goal using Pythons's [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) function, like so:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("<starting folder here>", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name == "tv.sas7bdat":
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

p.s: as for comments in your question, next time please provide as many details possible in your question and provide code of your attempt, see the [asking guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the short details  I thought my question is very obvious and clear, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**You can try the following code, where PATH stands for the parent directory**

```
import os
def getAlldirInDiGui(path,resultList):
    filesList=os.listdir(path)
    for fileName in filesList:
        fileAbpath=os.path.join(path,fileName)
        if os.path.isdir(fileAbpath):
            getAlldirInDiGui(fileAbpath,resultList)
        else:
            if fileName=='tv.sas7bdat':
                resultList.append(fileAbpath)
resultList = []
PATH = ""
getAlldirInDiGui(PATH,resultList)
```

Comment: Nothing happens !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.walk()`

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for f in files:
        if f.find("tv.sas7bdat")>=0:
            print(root,f)
```

Comment: Where to indicate the path of the directory, please

Comment: Sorry, you can remove the ```os.getcwd()``` and give the path of your directory. ```os.getcwd()``` takes the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Hope fully below code should work for you:

```
import glob
initial_path = "c:\<intital folder location>"
files = [file for file in glob.glob(initial_path+ "tv.sas7bdat" , recursive=True)]
for f in files:
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `os` python package combined with a recursive function to search through a certain directory

```
import os
from os.path import isfile, join, isdir

def get_files_path(directory, paths):
    for item in os.listdir(directory):
        if isfile(join(directory, item)) and item == "tv.sas7bda":
            paths.append(directory + item)
        elif isdir(directory+item):
            get_files_path(directory + item, paths)
    return paths

directory_to_search = "./"
get_files_path(directory_to_search , [])
```

Comment: Can you please indicate where i should enter the Directory path ?

Comment: you should enter it in the variable directory_to_search ^^

Comment: yes i have done that, but still showing : directory not defined

Comment: My bad I had written the wrong variable name when I was calling the function. I edited my answer, try again while putting your directory in the directory_to_search variable :)